# SQL: How to ORDER BY column(s)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with two columns. I need to ORDER the first column in ascending order, however when I run my query I don't get the result I'm looking for.

This the current output I'm getting when running my SELECT query:

```
  Retailer     AccountsOpened

1  Retailer 1  1
2  Retailer 2  1
3  Retailer 3  1
4  Mobichoice  1
5  Retailer 1  3
6  Retailer 2  3
7  Retailer 3  3
8  Mobichoice  3
9  Retailer 1  2
10 Retailer 2  2
11 Retailer 3  2
12 Mobichoice  2
```

I've tried to ORDER BY Retailer (ASC) and AccountsOpened but that doesn't work.  The code I tried is below:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 1 ORDER BY Retailer ASC, AccountsOpened
```

The output I want to see should be the following:

```
  Retailer     AccountsOpened

1  Retailer 1  1
2  Retailer 1  2
3  Retailer 1  3
4  Retailer 2  1
5  Retailer 2  2
6  Retailer 2  3
7  Retailer 3  1
8  Retailer 3  2
9  Retailer 3  3
10 Mobichoice  1
11 Mobichoice  2
12 Mobichoice  3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're mixing retailer column order here. M comes before R, but you put the Mobichoice rows after the Retailer rows. Interally your Retailer rows are in ASC order.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression to put the Mobichoice rows after the different Retailer rows.

```
SELECT * FROM Table 1
ORDER BY case when Retailer = 'Mobichoice' then 2 else 1 end,
         Retailer ASC, AccountsOpened
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, however I also wanted to be ordered in the format 1,2,3.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I don't get you. My answer will give you the result you've specified.